# Scraping data off site that requires login

Tags: python, python-requests

Very new to programming and trying to access data that requires a login. Just trying to understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = "https://buy.adesa.com/openauction/home.html"
    USERNAME = "userid"
    PASSWORD = "password"
    login_data = dict(username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD)
    c.post(url,data=login_data)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use the correct login url, the one that is defined in the form element, which is in this case https://login2.adesa.com/ssoserver/auth

Comment: So I changed it to the URL you suggested.

socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03AB7F10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.adesa.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ssoserver/auth (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03AB7F10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))

Comment: There are other hidden elements that are being posted, you need to have them all correctly set and sent to that url.

Comment: Ok how can i find out which elements need to be posted?

Comment: That's is not a python-related question. Inspect the page source and/or open Network tab on Chrome developer tools for example and see what is being sent.